# Make Pressable First Responder Touch - Override Keyboard

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, touch-event

When the keyboard is visible, I want to be able to press on one of the cells without having the keyboard hide first. Ideally it would be pressed and the keyboard hides after.

I have tried to set the address cell component's `onStartShouldSetResponder` to `true` and that had no effect.

```
<Pressable
  onStartShouldSetResponder={() => true}
  ...
```

Is there something I am missing with how touch gestures are handled in React Native?

[image: keyboard hiding first]

Answer (score 0):

Adding `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` to the `FlatList` component that renders the address cells seemed to solve this issue on iOS (have not tested on Android).

```
<FlatList
  keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
  ...
/>
```